# Variables defined in group_vars/file used within same file not working

Tags: ansible

Here's what i am trying to do with ansiblef:

group_vars/file1

file1 looks something like below:

var1: value1

var2: /some-path/{{ var1 }}

On execution of playbook on target nodes the output is like below:

/some-path/{}

Isn't the variable substitution supposed to work in this manner ?

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you declare the var2 as

`var2: "/some-path/{{ var1 }}"` or `var2: '/some-path/{{ var1 }}'`